# How to get a Hash Map which is parsed to JSON?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I previously have a list which is parsed to JSON and received in the other end like this:

```
List<Model> list = Arrays.asList(restTemplatelist.getForObject("http://dataurl, Model[].class));
```

Now I want the same method but this time I need a HashMap which is parsed to JSON and I have to receive as a HashMap.

```
Map<String, Object> combinedMap =restTemplatemap.getForObject("http://dataurl);
```

But this does not work.Any help is appreciated

Comment: Refer to the method info here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#getForObject(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Map <String, Object> combinedMap =restTemplatemap.getForObject("http://dataurl", Map.class);
```

Keep in mind the values of the returned Map Object should be able to cast to Value `Object` type you mention in your combinedMap type.